# Connect a slicer to ll pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

Status Quo:
I have an excel 2010 workbook with a worksheet named *Data*. All the pivot tables in the workbook draw from that sheet. I have another sheet named *Board* where all the slicers are, and every slicer is connected to all pivot tables in the workbook.

Need:
I have to overhaul the file quite often, adding some columns in *Data* and some more pivots and slicers. Of course, pivot cache won't update automatically. Therefor new pivots can't be associated to old slicers.

Strategy:
1_ I'd like to get a macro to detach all slicers from all pivot tables. This way if I add a new pivot I don't need to go through every slicer once again to link it.
2_ then I'd like to set all pivot caches to what I decide (Range("A1").CurrentRegion on *Data* seems pretty cool, otherwise I could reserve a cell on *Board* that I update manually).
3_ third and last, attach every slicer to every pivot table in the workbook.

Achievements:
1_ did it for 1 slicer, guess a loop will do the trick
2_ kinda did it, but...meh
3_ no way. I can't get this done.

Any suggestions?
Thank you for your help, this would be really a time saver!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently I did it!!
I took some code from the internet, I forgot where.
Hope this is useful to someone!!!

```
Sub ManageSlicers(Connect_Disconnect As String)
'feed in *connect* or *disconnect* accordingly to get it applied to all slicers in *Board*.
Dim oSlicer As Slicer
Dim oSlicercache As SlicerCache
'
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each oSlicercache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each oSlicer In oSlicercache.Slicers
        If oSlicer.Shape.BottomRightCell.Worksheet.Name = "Board" Then
            For Each wks In Worksheets
                For Each pt In wks.PivotTables
                    If Connect_Disconnect = "connect" Then
                        oSlicer.SlicerCache.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (Sheets(wks.Name).PivotTables(pt.Name))
                    ElseIf Connect_Disconnect = "disconnect" Then
                        oSlicer.SlicerCache.PivotTables.RemovePivotTable (Sheets(wks.Name).PivotTables(pt.Name))
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Macro ManageSlicers messed up."
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

Set oSlicer = Nothing
Set oSlicercache = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
End Sub

Sub UpdatePivotCache()
'update pivottables cache
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In wks.PivotTables
        If lIndex = 0 Then
            pt.ChangePivotCache _
                ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                SourceData:=Sheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
            Set ptMain = pt
            lIndex = 1
        Else
            pt.CacheIndex = ptMain.CacheIndex
        End If
    Next pt
Next wks
End Sub

Sub RefreshSlicersAndPivots()
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Call ManageSlicers("disconnect")
Call UpdatePivotCache
Call ManageSlicers("connect")
End Sub
```